# phpLiteAdmin - Adding Images

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

An application I am presently working on requires an SQLite database.
As I will not be the one actually maintaining the database I believe it would be tremendously beneficial to use a tool such phpLiteAdmin. However, I need a way to store an image as a blob in the table (I know there are some pitfalls with storing the actual image data in the database, but for my purposes I believe it is the best approach). Is there any way to do so with a GUI tool such as phpLiteAdmin or not? Could I somehow write a custom function to implement this behavior if it is available by default?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As current lead developer of phpLiteAdmin, I can say for sure that it currently does not support uploading images into blob fields...
Of course you can insert blob literals as explained by CL., but this might be too cumbersome.

I created an issue in our issue tracker though:
https://bitbucket.org/phpliteadmin/public/issues/305/
We will add this feature for sure in some upcoming version.

**Edit 23.02.2017:**
I just implemented managing BLOB fields in phpLiteAdmin. It will be available in upcoming version 1.9.8 and can be already tested in the development version: http://www.phpliteadmin.org/phpliteadmin-dev.zip

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you could store image's file name in a char type column. For example, there is a column img_filename in your table. Then you can simply show the image in HTML with `<img src='...'>` tag:

```
<?php

// your database query here
// ...

print "<img src='".$row['img_filename']."' />"


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tool does not have a function to upload a file into a blob, then the only way to create a blob is to execute an INSERT or UPDATE query with a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) (which you still have to construct somehow):

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(Blob) VALUES(x'001122');
```